# SQL -- Are there are any rows where a column value is greater than 6?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables.

`AT_lesson_assignments` has the following as columns: assignment_id, course_id, unit
`AT_lesson_assignments_visibility` has the following as columns: assignment_id, course_id

I'm trying to come up with a way to see if there are any entries in `AT_lesson_assignments` in which `unit` is greater than 6 **that also** exist on the `AT_lesson_assignments_visibility` table.

The logic would be something like...

1.) Select all assignment_id's from `AT_lesson_assignments` where course_id = $course_id AND unit > 6.

2.) Check to see if any of those assignment_id's are in `AT_lesson_assignments_visibility`.

3.) Return true if there is a match, otherwise return false.

I'm not good at all with sql queries, so I'm not really sure where to begin.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=join the two tables using assignment_id then add where clause

```
select * from
`AT_lesson_assignments`  aa 
inner join `AT_lesson_assignments_visibility` at on aa.assignment_id = at.assignment_id
where unit > 6
```

Comment: @Unihedron "special types"? It's not necessary to quote fields unless they are reserved words.

Comment: I take it you are showing him where to start as opposed to presenting a query that gives the answer.